# How to change only one javascript function in wordpress child theme?

Tags: themes, child-theme

I would like to change just one JavaScript function in the child theme but without having to insert all the JavaScript code of the parent theme.

How do I change only this function (I need change only `count = Math.ceil(width / size)` line):

```
function slickAutoResponsive(slider, max, size) {

  if (!max){
    max = 5;
  }
  if (!size){
    size = 380;
  }

  var width = slider.width(),
    count = Math.ceil(width / size);

  if (count < 1) count = 1;
  if (count > max) count = max;

  return count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: You can't. That code doesn't have any mechanism to filter it. You would need to replace the entire JavaScript file.